# working with variables

Tags: vb.net

I am new to .net and was wondering how I could add 2 registry search items into their own variable?

e.g. Using the below code, I would like **Software\test2** and **Software\test1** put into their own variable if found so I can use in another section of code for removal.

The code I am using is:

```
If Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\test2") Is Nothing Then Label2.Text = ""Else ListBox1.Items.Add("Software\test2")
        If Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\test1") Is Nothing Then Label2.Text = "" Else ListBox1.Items.Add("Software\test1")
```

Comment: `Dim st1 As String = "Software\test1"`

Answer (score 0):

When you call `OpenSubKey`, it will return a `RegistryKey` object for the subkey you just opened.  The first thing to do is to assign the result of that function to a variable.  You can then call `GetValue` on that `RegistryKey` and assign the result of that function to another variable.

Comment: Thanks for this, I am totally new to VB. I will have multiple searches (100+) and I am trying to compact my code. The code will include a search section and delete section if any of the values are found. Would I have to assign "Dim st1 As String = "Software\test1" for example to each OpenSubKey search?

Comment: All that does is assign that `String` to a variable.  You can do that or not but it's irrelevant to the rest of the process.  You call `OpenSubKey` and pass a `String` containing the name of the subkey as an argument.  Whether that argument is a literal or variable doesn't matter.  The `OpenSubKey` method returns a `RegistryKey` object and you would assign that to a variable and then call `GetValue` on that.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. Not sure if I should start a new question but is there an easier way of deleting found items instead of     `My.Computer.Registry.CurrentUser.DeleteSubKey("Software\Test")` for each item found which would be 100+

Comment: It doesn't really matter how many there are because you'd use a loop so the code would be exactly the same regardless.

Comment: I am not really using loop at this stage just line by line. Not really sure how to loop with what I need to do just yet

Comment: You should learn now because it sounds like it is completely appropriate in this instance.  Looping is one of the basic constructs of programming so you should be able to do it fairly well before you consider trying to edit the Registry.